# Forge Viewer AR

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We have eagerly and daily been watching [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/conxtech-rethinking-job-site-apples-arkit-forge) blogpost for any update on the source code. Our team are really interested in looking into AR technology similar to that integrated with the Forge Viewer. Does any of the Forge developers happen to know whether there's any updates coming or if there's any other AR material to look into at the moment? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pex.  That blog post should have a reference to the 'beta sign up' page.  I'll update it now.

You should start with the signup page to give you a feel for the toolkit.  Unfortunately, we have found an issue with load performance for large scenes we are addressing.  This has delayed that blog post and release of that source code.

Here is the beta sign up page:  beta.autodesk.com/
and then select: 'AR|VR Toolkit'

There is a downloads section and tutorials as well as a beta-forum to add your feedback.

Let me know if you have trouble with the signup.

Comment: Hi michael, thanks for reaching out and assisting! Appreciated. We'll go ahead and register ourselves. Looks interesting! Thanks.